# SQL: How to update multiple values using a subquery that has group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-update, subquery

I have the below table:

```
row_date    logid   type    Interval   availtime    avail_distribution
9/25/2013    122     4       850         640            NULL
9/25/2013    122     5       850         0              NULL
9/25/2013    122     7       850         0              NULL
9/26/2013    122     4       850         500            NULL
9/26/2013    122     5       850         0              NULL
9/26/2013    122     7       850         0              NULL
```

Here each of `avail_distribution` is to be updated by the average of the `availtime, group by row_date,logid and Interval`.

The required table after update:

```
row_date    logid   type    Interval   availtime    avail_distribution
9/25/2013   122      4        850        640            213.3333
9/25/2013   122      5        850        0              213.3333
9/25/2013   122      7        850        0              213.3333
9/26/2013   122      4        850        500            167.66667
9/26/2013   122      5        850        0              167.66667
9/26/2013   122      7       850         0              167.66667
```

---

```
Select sum(availtime)/count(availtime) 
 from table 
 group by row_date,logid,Interval;
```

gives me the values that  I  am seeking.. but I am not able to update the `avail_distribution` column the way I am intending.

Comment: Why do you need to update the table? So you can constantly keep updating it every time the data changes? Why not just calculate the distribution at query time, then you don't have to perform updates, you don't need that wasteful column, and the result is always guaranteed to be up to date?

Answer (score 2):

Using a CTE ([Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms175972.aspx)) will allow you to easily perform any grouping / logic required before you do the actual update.

```
;WITH cte_update as (
    Select 
        row_date,
        logid,
        Interval,
        sum(availtime)/count(availtime) as avail_dist
    from 
        table 
    group by 
        row_date,
        logid,
        Interval )

update t
set 
    t.avail_distribution = cte.avail_dist
from 
    table as t
    inner join cte_update as cte 
        on t.row_date = cte.row_date 
        and t.logid = cte.logid 
        and t.interval = cte.interval
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.avail_distribution = b.val
FROM TableName a INNER JOIN
    ( Select  row_date,logid,Interval,
            sum(availtime)/count(availtime) val
    from  [Table] group by row_date,logid,Interval
    ) b ON a.row_date = b.row_date AND
        a.logid = b.logid AND
        a.Interval = c.Interval
```

But why do you store data like this? in the long run, you will execute this script always to update the column which is a little overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of updating this data...

```
Declare @Data Table
(
    row_date datetime,
    logid int,
    type int,
    Interval int,
    availtime float,
    avail_distribution float
);

Insert Into @Data(row_date,logid,type,Interval,availtime) Values 
('9/25/2013', 122, 4, 850, 640),
('9/25/2013', 122, 5, 850, 0),
('9/25/2013', 122, 7, 850, 0),
('9/26/2013', 122, 4, 850, 500),
('9/26/2013', 122, 5, 850, 0),
('9/26/2013', 122, 7, 850, 0);


;WITH CTE
as
(
    Select *, Avg(availtime) Over (partition by row_date,logid,Interval) 
    as value_of_avail_distribution from @Data
)
Update CTE Set avail_distribution = value_of_avail_distribution

select * from @Data
```